# Received OnSerialization for view ID xxxx. We have no such PhotonView! Ignore this if you're joining or leaving a room. State: Joined

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am a beginner who just started using Photon. I'm making a 2D battle royale game like surviv.io,  but Error occurs when bullets destroyed. how can I Destroy networked-object perfect?

this is my script.

<Bullet Script>

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Pool;
using Photon.Pun;

public class BulletView : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start() => Destroy(gameObject, 2.5f);
    public PhotonView PV;
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D hitInfo)
    {
        if (hitInfo.tag == "Border") Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

<Player Script>

```
using Photon.Pun;
using Cinemachine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Realtime;
using Hashtable = ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable;
using UnityEngine.Pool;

public class PlayerView : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks,IPunObservable
{
    private Vector3 dir;
    public Camera cam;
    public float bulletSpeed;

    float angle;
    Vector2 target, mouse;
    public PhotonView PV;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    public Vector3 remotePos;
    public Quaternion remoteRot;

    public float MoveSpeed = 250f;

    public Transform Shootpos;
    public GameObject Bulletprefab;

    public GameObject InvisibleLayer;
    public GameObject TeamColor;

    Vector2 MoveMent = new Vector2();

    void Awake()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
        if (PV.IsMine)
        {
            TeamColor.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.green;
            // 2D 카메라
            var CM = GameObject.Find("CMcamera").GetComponent<CinemachineVirtualCamera>();
            CM.Follow = transform;
            CM.LookAt = transform;
        }
        else
        {
            TeamColor.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
            InvisibleLayer.SetActive(false);
            ChangeLayer("Enemy");
        }
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (PV.IsMine)
        {
            if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                dir = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, -cam.transform.position.z));
                photonView.RPC("SpawnBullet", RpcTarget.AllBuffered, dir);
            }
        }
        if (!photonView.IsMine)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, remotePos, 10 * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, remoteRot, 10 * Time.deltaTime);

            return;
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (PV.IsMine)
        {
            Move();
            Turn();
        }
    }

    public void ChangeLayer(string name)
    {
        ChangeLayersRecursively(transform, name);
    }

    public void ChangeLayersRecursively(Transform trans, string name)
    {
        trans.gameObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer(name);
        foreach (Transform child in trans)
        {
            ChangeLayersRecursively(child, name);
        }
    }
    void Move()
    {
        MoveMent.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        MoveMent.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        MoveMent.Normalize();
        rb.velocity = MoveMent * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    void Turn()
    {
        target = transform.position;
        mouse = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        angle = Mathf.Atan2(mouse.y - target.y, mouse.x - target.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle - 90, Vector3.forward);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    void SpawnBullet(Vector3 dir)
    {

        GameObject bullet = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("Bullet", Shootpos.position, Quaternion.identity);
        bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = (dir - transform.position).normalized * bulletSpeed;
    }

    public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {
        if (stream.IsWriting)
        {
            stream.SendNext(transform.position);
            stream.SendNext(transform.rotation);
        }
        else 
        {
            remotePos = (Vector3)stream.ReceiveNext();
            remoteRot = (Quaternion)stream.ReceiveNext();
        }
    }
}
```

<Game Manager(Not related to Bullet)>

```
using Photon.Pun;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Minimap;
    public Transform[] SpawnPoints=new Transform[6];
    private void Awake()
    {
        int spawnpos = (int)PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.CustomProperties["Spawnpos"];
        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("PlayerController", SpawnPoints[spawnpos].position, Quaternion.identity);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.T))
        {
            Minimap.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Minimap.SetActive(false);
        }
    
    }
}
```

This Is Error Message

Received OnSerialization for view ID xxxx. We have no such PhotonView! Ignore this if you're joining or leaving a room. State: Joined

How can I Fix the Error?

I Tried [PunRPC] like this, but it not worked

```
        if (hitInfo.tag == "Border") PV.RPC("DestroyRPC", RpcTarget.AllBuffered);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    void DestroyRPC()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```